# Is there any difference between "told to" and "told to do so"

Tags: phrases, sentence, ellipses

> I will release a new version when I'm told to.
>
> I will release a new version when I'm told to do so.

Is there any difference in the meaning of the two sentences? Which one would I use in an everyday conversation?

Comment: Both mean the same thing and you can use both in everyday conversation. One is simply an ellipsis of the other.

Comment: As usual, longer versions with all the parts left in are more emphatic, which can come in handy for expressing (for example) determination not to yield to unauthorized attempts to force release.

Comment: The second *might* be perceived as slightly less rude.  But a lot depends on verbal emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

RegDwigнt is correct in saying (in a comment above), "Both mean the same thing and you can use both in everyday conversation. One is simply an ellipsis of the other." Having seconded his observation, I note also that the version without ellipsis can sound somewhat stiffer than the version with ellipsis. This is less obvious in the pair

> I will release a new version when I'm told to.
>
> I will release a new version when I'm told to do so.

than in the pair

> You can come with me if you want to.
>
> You can come with me if you want to do so.

—but I think it's detectable in both instances. The difference in formal or informal tone may be what John Lawler was getting at in his comment above: "As usual, longer versions with all the parts left in are more emphatic, ..."

In any case, the more formal the contextual setting is, the more natural the full version sounds and the more casually brusque the shortened version becomes; and conversely, the more informal the contextual setting is, the more wooden the full version sounds and the more tonally appropriate the shortened version becomes.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatically, it's possible to read the first as more *allowing* but not *requiring* the action, while the second involves a command. In other words, the first has something of the sense of:

> I will release a new version when I'm permitted to

while the second is a bit more like:

> I will release a new version when I'm commanded to

It's subtle though. Literally, @RegDwight is correct to note that they are identical